# IOS App to decode a frame and display using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer fails

Tags: ios, ios8

I am writing a IOS App which will decode a H.264 frame and render using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer. I have already modified the frame to not have the NAL start code but have a 4 byte NAL size. This has been verified.

But all i see is a white frame in my IOS simulator, No error; is there a possibility to dump the decoded frame and verify? Any other debug points will really help.

```
@implementation DecodeClass

- (void) viewDidLoad {
}

/* method to decode and render a frame */
- (void)decodeFrame{
NSLog(@"Decode Start");

/* local variable declaration */

//OSStatus status;
size_t spsSize, ppsSize,dataLen;
//_frameSize = 320*240*1.5;

uint8_t sps[] = {0x67, 0x42, 0xC0, 0x0D, 0x96, 0x64, 0x0A, 0x0F, 0xDF, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x18, 0x80, 0x00,
                 0x00, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0xB5, 0x47, 0x8A, 0x15, 0x50};

uint8_t pps[] = {0x68, 0xCE, 0x32, 0xC8};

const uint8_t* props[] = {sps, pps};
spsSize = (sizeof(sps)/sizeof(uint8_t));
ppsSize = (sizeof(pps)/sizeof(uint8_t));
const size_t sizes[] = {spsSize,ppsSize};

FILE* pFile;
int result;
pFile = fopen("/Documents/input_mod1.264","r");
fseeko(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long fileSize = ftello(pFile);
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
_dataBuf = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * (fileSize));
memset(_dataBuf,0,sizeof(uint8_t) * (fileSize));

if (pFile ){
        result = fread(_dataBuf,sizeof(uint8_t),fileSize,pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
}
else
    NSLog(@"Can't open file");

[self MUX_Modify_AVC_Start_Code:_dataBuf size:&fileSize Header:false];
dataLen = fileSize;

//construct h.264 parameter set
CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef formatDesc;
OSStatus formatCreateResult =  CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets(kCFAllocatorDefault, 2, props, sizes, 4, &formatDesc);
if (formatCreateResult)
{
    NSLog(@"construct CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets Failed :%ld",(long)formatCreateResult);
}

//construct cmBlockbuffer .
CMBlockBufferRef blockBufferOut = nil;
CMBlockBufferCreateEmpty (0,0,kCMBlockBufferAlwaysCopyDataFlag, &blockBufferOut);

CMBlockBufferAppendMemoryBlock(blockBufferOut,
                               _dataBuf,
                               dataLen,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               0,
                               dataLen,
                               kCMBlockBufferAlwaysCopyDataFlag);

//construct cmsamplebuffer ok
size_t sampleSizeArray[1] = {0};
sampleSizeArray[0] = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferOut);    
CMSampleTimingInfo tmInfos[1] = {
    {CMTimeMake(5,1), CMTimeMake(5,1), CMTimeMake(5,1)}
};
CMSampleBufferRef sampBuf = nil;
formatCreateResult = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          blockBufferOut,
                                          YES,
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL,
                                          formatDesc,
                                          1,
                                          1,
                                          tmInfos,
                                          1,
                                          sampleSizeArray,
                                          &sampBuf);
NSLog(@"Decode End :: Construct CMSampleBufferRef value of formatCreateResult is %d", formatCreateResult);

if(!_dspLayer)
{
    _dspLayer = [[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer alloc]init];
    [_dspLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,240)];
    _dspLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    _dspLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    _dspLayer.position = CGPointMake(500, 500);
    _dspLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    CMTimebaseRef tmBase = nil;
     CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock(NULL,CMClockGetHostTimeClock(),&tmBase);
    _dspLayer.controlTimebase = tmBase;
    CMTimebaseSetTime(_dspLayer.controlTimebase, kCMTimeZero);
    CMTimebaseSetRate(_dspLayer.controlTimebase, 1.0);

    [self.layerView.layer addSublayer:_dspLayer];
}

//put to AVSampleBufferdisplayLayer,just one frame.
if([self.dspLayer isReadyForMoreMediaData])
{
    [self.dspLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampBuf];
}
[self.dspLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)MUX_Modify_AVC_Start_Code:(uint8_t*)pData size:(uint32_t *)nSize Header:(bool)bHeader{
....
}

-(uint32_t)MUX_FindNextPattern:(uint8_t*)streamBuf buffSize:(uint32_t)bufSize startCode:(uint32_t)startcode{
....
}

- (void)dealloc{
//free(_dataBuf);
}

@end


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

//[decodeClass release];
@autoreleasepool {
    DecodeClass *decodeClass = [[DecodeClass alloc]init];
    [decodeClass decodeFrame];
    decodeClass = nil;
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,   NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, any pointers/comments?

Comment: What does `MUX_Modify_AVC_Start_Code` do? The NAL length code needs to be in big-endian byte order.

Comment: Hi Greg, MUX_Modify_AVC_Start_Code replaces startcode with 4byte NAL length and is in big-endian byte order. I was able to fx this; the issues was is was not setting the view correctly.

Comment: Hi Greg, MUX_Modify_AVC_Start_Code replaces startcode with 4byte NAL length and is in big-endian byte order. I was able to fx this; the issues was is was not setting the view correctly.